# Clicking cookie button with Selenium 4 error: object[] has no size and location

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been attempting to click a button in a pop-up with selenium, but I'm getting the following error:

```
object [HTMLDivElement] has no size and location
```

I have tried the normal way, with just click, since it is in the viewport and I am waiting for the page to fully load:

```js
let pressCookieButton = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//a[@class="btn-actiune btn-actiune--principal"]/..'))
await pressCookieButton.click();
```

But this does not work. It says

```
Element not interactible
```

Then, i tried to click using actions:

```js
let pressCookieButton = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//a[@class="btn-actiune btn-actiune--principal"]/..'))
const actions = driver.actions({ async: true });
await actions.click(pressCookieButton).perform();
```

But i get:

```
object [HTMLDivElement] has no size and location
```

The HTML that I am attempting to click is the following:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> 
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="modCookies.updatePermisiuniCookies('toate');" class="btn-actiune btn-actiune--principal">Accept toate cookie-urile</a>  
</div>
```

Below is the full code:

```js
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {By} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function helloSelenium() {

    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

    try{

        await driver.get('https://www.imobiliare.ro/vanzare-apartamente/timisoara/matei-basarab/apartament-de-vanzare-3-camere-XCB61020C');
    
        await driver.sleep(7000);
        console.log("clicking")
    
        
        let pressCookieButton = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//a[@class="btn-actiune btn-actiune--principal"]/..'))

        
        const actions = driver.actions({ async: true });
        await actions.click(pressCookieButton).perform();
    
        //findElement(By.className('btn-actiune btn-actiune--principal'));
        await driver.sleep(10000);
    
        await pressCookieButton.click();
    
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)

        await driver.sleep(5000);

        // await driver.quit()
    }
    
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the GIF below, the xpath matches two elements and by using `driver.findElement` you are selecting the first one, while the correct one is the second.

So you should either use `driver.findElements` instead of `driver.findElement` and then select the second element, or use a selector targetting only the correct element, such as

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div[class*="vizibil-informare"] a[class*="principal"]'))
```

[image]